# Test to see if jQuery or Prototype is queued by another plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, javascript

In my plugin, I want to test to see if jQuery or Prototype (or both) are going to be loaded by another plugin. So, have [`wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) or `wp_enqueue_script('prototype')` has already been called.

I have code appropriate to my plugin in files `plugin.prototype.js` and `plugin.jquery.js` and if Prototype is queued, my plugin will use `plugin.prototype.js`. This way I avoid loading more than necessary into the site. If neither has loaded, I will queue up whichever is smaller.

How can I test to see what has been queued up? How do I make sure my code runs last?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `wp_script_is()` to check if a script is in the queue.

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    $doing_jquery = wp_script_is('jquery', 'queue');
    $doing_prototype = wp_script_is('prototype', 'queue');

    var_dump($doing_jquery, $doing_prototype);
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'add_my_scripts');
```

Comment: So does the `wp_print_scripts` hook get executed right before, during or right after the scripts have printed?

Comment: It prints the scripts, so... during. :) You should use the [add_action() priority argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to make your function run later.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. The wp_print_scripts action runs (allowing you to enqueue your scripts), and the scripts are printed after all the wp_print_script actions are done.

Comment: I was unaware of `wp_script_is` - seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: Related to this, can you tell me how to handle plugin script collisions like jQuery Apprise or other popular component? See question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49020/13

Answer (score 2):

To make sure your code runs after jQuery or Prototype is loaded, use the `$deps` parameter to `wp_enqueue_script`, and pass either `array('jquery')` or `array('prototype')`. If you want to know whether a script is in the queue, you can use [the `query()` method of `WP_Dependencies`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php#L184) ([which is the superclass of `WP_Scripts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L19)). So something like this should work:

```
global $wp_scripts;
$jQueryIsLoaded = (bool) $wp_scripts->query('jquery');
$prototypeIsLoaded = (bool) $wp_scripts->query('prototype');
```

Of course, plugins could enqueue them after you decided on one, so try to make sure you execute this check at the last possible moment.

Comment: How do I execute at the last possible moment?

Comment: Silly me, I didn't see that [`wp_script_is`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L122) does this for you, so [Adam's answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206/test-to-see-if-jquery-or-prototype-is-queued-by-another-plugin/209#209) is the way to go, including the use of the `wp_print_scripts` hook (which is indeed called just before the scripts are printed, so you can add new scripts there).