# jquery script not enqueued in child theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme

I need a little bit of insight here with the following problem? I've created a child theme called 'test_child' which I am trying to extend in the following way:

This is the test_child/functions.php file:

```
<?php

function load_flaticon() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
            'flaticon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/flaticon.js', array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_flaticon' );

?>
```

Then, this is the test_child/js/flaticon.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('flaticon-pdf19');
    $("a[href$='.ppt']").addClass('flaticon-ppt');
    $("a[href$='.pptx']").addClass('flaticon-pptx2');
    $("a[href$='.doc']").addClass('flaticon-doc2'); 
    $("a[href$='.docx']").addClass('flaticon-docx'); 
    $("a[href$='.xls']").addClass('flaticon-xls1');
    $("a[href$='.xlsx']").addClass('flaticon-xlsx');  
});
// by the way have already tried the " .ready(function() { " version
```

Inside the test_child/header.php I can see somewhere the line:

```
<!-- wp_head() -->
<?php wp_head();?>
```

I believe I'm doing it 'by the book' (and I have studied other similar questions), but then again, there must be something I miss, because the script is not enqueued after all...

Could you please lend a fresh pair of eyes?

Comment: Try the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: @PieterGoosen The asker explained the problem very clear, showed research efforts and code to reproduce the problem. This is one of the best first questions I have seen for a long time.

Comment: Sorry @toscho, sorry about that. I actually see your point here, and I do agree on that. Will remove my comment. Thanks for pointing that out. +1.

Comment: I tried `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_script` and it worked like a charm! Thank you for your suggestion @toscho. (P.S. Sorry for my bad grammar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts in the question I want to address:

1. It didn’t work because the action uses a plural form: `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `wp_enqueue_script`. I guess this happened, because the function you have to use here – `wp_enqueue_script()` – *does* use a singular.
2. You should not use the function `wp_enqueue_script()` with so many parameters.

   **Register** your scripts early, **enqueue** them late.

   ```
   function register_flaticon() {
       wp_register_script(
           'flaticon',
           get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/flaticon.js',
           array('jquery')
       );
   }
   function enqueue_flaticon() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'flaticon' );
   }

   add_action( 'wp_loaded',          'register_flaticon' );
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_flaticon' );
   ```

   The reason for that is flexibility. There are **four** enqueue actions:

   - `wp_enqueue_scripts`
   - `admin_enqueue_scripts`
   - `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`
   - `login_enqueue_scripts`

   If you register your script early enough, you or someone else can enqueue it then on one of the other actions, and [collisions can be avoided](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49020/73), because WordPress will not register a script with the same handle twice. See also this thread about the [naming convention for jQuery addons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/58226/73).

Comment: Yesterday, I tried to hardcode the script into the <head>. I know now, it's totally wrong (I feel shame.. :) ), and yet I didn't even know how to do that. Imagine the ground I covered, before posting my question.

Your answer not only unstuck me and made my code functional, but you also helped me understand how and why to further improve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will open the current child theme directory uri, therefore, it will not get the specified file because it is child theme

To get the file use `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the directory path this will get template directory which you have specified in style.css i.e

```
Template:your_parent_theme_folder_name
```