# How resource intensive is wp_register_script()?

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-script, performance, wp-register-script

I'm trying to use the `has_shortcode()` function to only load certain scripts when there is a shortcode in the post's content, with this code:

```
wp_register_script( 'shortcode-js-file' , FILE_URI, array( 'jquery'), '', true );

if(isset($post->post_content) && has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'shortcode_name')) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'shortcode-js-file');
}
```

So in the above code, I'm registering the script on all pages, whether there is that shortcode in the post or not, and if there is that shortcode, then I'm enqueuing the script for it.

What I want to know is whether I should put the `wp_register_script` inside the `if` statement or not. If it is not too resource intensive then I would rather leave it outside, as I want to put all the `wp_register_script` code together in one function.

PS. To showcase my problem clearly, I didn't add the hook and functions that I'm using, as it's not important for what I want to inquire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_register_script()` just adds an entry to an array, it doesn’t do anything resource intensive. See `WP_Dependencies::add()`.

Registering scripts early [helps to avoid collisions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143164/73), so you should do that always on `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. However, isn't it always best to use the wp_enqueue_scripts hook for registering and enqueing scripts?

Comment: @user1981248 No, use both separate functions on both separate actions. This is why there *are* two functions, not just one.