# Is it the right way to add jquery and css in wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development

```
function dwwp_admin_enqueue_scripts_mlm() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dwwp-admin-css', plugins_url( 'css/admin-users.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-users', plugins_url( 'js/admin-users.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css' );}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dwwp_admin_enqueue_scripts_mlm' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As wordpress codex states, you should use jquery and other javascript files provided by them. As for css files I think you can use yours.

Please check [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)( scroll down) for a list of already defined javascript files.

Also, you have to use local files as much as possible, unless you have no other way. So for example, if you have a js library, you should download it and include it in your theme/plugin files and not enqueue it using CDN or any other external link. Wordpress team will refuse to publish your theme/plugin if you include external js files without a good reason.

LE: for jquery-ui you only have to use this

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui')
```

or add it as a dependency of your own script like this

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', 'url-to-scrip', array('jquery-ui'))
```

Comment: Yes Okay..now it's works fine.I downloaded jquery and make it offline

Comment: I guess you downloaded the css for jquery and not js files. As @toscho says, do not try to override already existing js files as you may end up in a conflict

Comment: ohhk...i will try below solution

Comment: @P.Sheth why are you trying to add external jquery files?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not try to overwrite the libraries (jQuery, jQuery UI) that are already provided by WordPress. This will either fail or result in conflicts with other plugins.
2. [**Register** your assets early](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143164/73), **enqueue** them by their handle only.
3. Use the **dependency** parameter to make sure assets are loaded in the order you need.

So, you should do something like this:

```
if ( is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) )
{
    add_action(
        'wp_loaded',
        function() {
            wp_register_script(
                'admin-users',
                plugins_url( 'js/admin-users.js', __FILE__ ),
                [ 'jquery-ui-core' ] // Let WP handle the rest.
            );
            wp_register_style(
                'jquery-style',
                'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css'
            );
            wp_register_style(
                'dwwp-admin-css',
                plugins_url( 'css/admin-users.css', __FILE__ ),
                [ 'jquery-style' ]
            );
        }
    );
    add_action( 
        'admin_enqueue_scripts', 
        function() {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-users' );
            // jquery-style will be loaded automatically.
            wp_enqueue_style( 'dwwp-admin-css' );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: can you please show me how to add external jquery ?

Comment: @P.Sheth That's not possible in the admin area. WordPress will not allow it for good reasons: other plugins and **WordPress itself** will use the built-in one, and then you would have two versions of the same library loaded – debug hell. :)

Comment: For autocomplete suggestions i have to include jquery-1.12.4.js and jquery-ui.js. and i included but not working jquery properly.

Comment: @P.Sheth Use the built-in library `jquery-ui-autocomplete`. See `wp-ncludes/script-loader.php` for available libraries.

Comment: okay...and how to add this inbulit libraries?

Comment: @P.Sheth As a dependency. Replace `'jquery-ui-core'` with `'jquery-ui-autocomplete'` in my example, and WordPress will load the core and jQuery automatically.