# When to use add_action when registering/enqueuing scripts

Tags: filters, javascript, actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

When should you use `add_action` to enqueue or register a script, vs just using `wp_register_script` and/or `wp_enqueue_script`? In other words, both `example 1` and `example 2` below seem to accomplish the same thing when in `functions.php`, so why do so many resources say that `example 1` is the correct way of loading scripts in WP?

**Example 1:**

```
function my_assets() {
    wp_register_script( 'owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/owl.carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

**Example 2:**

```
wp_register_script( 'owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/owl.carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel' );
```

(yes, I know in example 2 you could skip registering the script and just enqueue it as necessary)

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143152/jquery-script-not-enqueued-in-child-theme?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. My question is why bother using "add_action" when it works just fine without it?

Comment: You get an error in development mode when you call these functions too early. That's not "just fine". :)

Comment: and you can also call them too late to do you any good

Answer (score 1):

Well it works the same *in the case where you tested it*.

The answer could actually be somewhat complex, but mainly having it inside an action callback only registers them when needed, just putting it inside the `functions.php` it happens always when the theme is active.

First of all this can be a waste of performance, registering stuff that is never used. You might think that it should be there in any case, but actually in WP there are plenty of situations where frontend JS/CSS is totally irrelevant. The most obvious situation is the backend. But also some plugin might create an endpoint that doesn't need JS/CSS. And there are plenty more of that.

Last but not least by having this on an action third party code (plugins, child themes) can unhook the callback to e.g. replace it with something else.

I hope this gives you a basic understanding why it is good practice to only do stuff on the appropriate hook.

To close things this could also be relevant/interesting for you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21579/47733

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is time. `wp_enqueue_scripts` makes sure that scripts are available when needed.

> wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that
>   are meant to appear on the front end.